# MySQL group concat not showing distinct values when joined to another table

Tags: mysql

I have one view that gives me comma separated values and want to use that data in another view. In the first view, I am using `group_concat( distinct` ...) and when I run that view by itself, I can see only the distinct values as expected.

However, when I join that view to another table, I am now getting duplicates.

```
SELECT
group_concat( distinct tag separator ', ') AS tag,
FROM
fruit
```

`tag` is already group_concated in the first view. Running this query gives me:

```
apples, oranges, apples, pears, figs, oranges
```

Apples and oranges are duplicated. Why is this?

**EDIT:**

I've paired this down as much as I could. Here is the view with no joins.

```
SELECT
tag
FROM
fruit
```

Here are the rows returned:

```
apples, oranges
apples, pears
figs, oranges
```

How do I get a group_concat for the column with an output of:

```
apples, oranges, pears, figs
```

Comment: Where is the JOIN query ???

Comment: I apologize for the misleading title, If I run the query just as it is, without a join, it still gives me duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I entered that data like this

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> drop table if exists fruit;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table fruit
    -> (
    ->   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ->   tag varchar(20) not null
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.45 sec)

mysql> insert into fruit (tag) values
    -> ('apples'),('oranges'),('apples'),('pears'),('figs'),('oranges');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Note the output of these queries

```
mysql> select tag from fruit;
+---------+
| tag     |
+---------+
| apples  |
| oranges |
| apples  |
| pears   |
| figs    |
| oranges |
+---------+
6 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> select distinct tag from fruit;
+---------+
| tag     |
+---------+
| apples  |
| oranges |
| pears   |
| figs    |
+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select group_concat(distinct tag) tag from fruit;
+---------------------------+
| tag                       |
+---------------------------+
| apples,oranges,pears,figs |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

According the info you just added to the question, each tag has two fruits. Please note that each tag field (holding two fruits) is unique. You should be storing the fruits as separate fields.

The [**GROUP_CONCAT function**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is for query aggregation, not set manipulation.

The only way to use the view is to do this convoluted solution

I reloaded the data like this first:

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> drop table if exists fruit;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> create table fruit
    -> (
    ->   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ->   tag varchar(20) not null
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.31 sec)

mysql> insert into fruit (tag) values
    -> ('apples, oranges'),('apples, pears'),('figs, oranges');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Here are the contents now

```
mysql> select tag from fruit;
+-----------------+
| tag             |
+-----------------+
| apples, oranges |
| apples, pears   |
| figs, oranges   |
+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select distinct tag from fruit;
+-----------------+
| tag             |
+-----------------+
| apples, oranges |
| apples, pears   |
| figs, oranges   |
+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Ready for the convoluted solution ???

Here is the code

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(subtag) fruits FROM (SELECT ''',
REPLACE(tags,', ',''' subtag UNION SELECT '''),''') A') INTO @TagSQL
FROM (select GROUP_CONCAT(tag separator ', ') tags FROM fruit) A;
SELECT @TagSQL\G
PREPARE s FROM @TagSQL; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

Here is the output

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(subtag) fruits FROM (SELECT ''',
    -> REPLACE(tags,', ',''' subtag UNION SELECT '''),''') A') INTO @TagSQL
    -> FROM (select GROUP_CONCAT(tag separator ', ') tags FROM fruit) A;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT @TagSQL\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@TagSQL: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(subtag) fruits FROM (SELECT 'apples' subtag UNION S
ELECT 'oranges' subtag UNION SELECT 'apples' subtag UNION SELECT 'pears' subtag
UNION SELECT 'figs' subtag UNION SELECT 'oranges') A
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, execute the SQL generated

```
mysql> PREPARE s FROM @TagSQL; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

+---------------------------+
| fruits                    |
+---------------------------+
| apples,oranges,pears,figs |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## I TOLD YOU IT WAS CONVOLUTED !!!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing `select distinct` on the query itself. Thank you Rolando! You went all out there for me and I appreciate it. I'll be back and let you know if that works.

Comment: Rolando, the tags are coming from a single table and then concated in the query. The database is very well normalized.

Comment: The tags in each row is seen by the GROUP_CONCAT as a single value. Thus, you are using GROUP_CONCAT to combine `apples, oranges` as the first value, `apples, pears` as the second value, and `figs, oranges` as the third value. Each pair is unique.

Comment: I see.. So as far as the group_concat function is concerned, it's doing its job then. What I need are distinct values for each row so if I forgo the fruit view and just join up the tables, I get what I need. I've already tested this but I want to be certain that there is no way to do it with the view first. Am I right?

Comment: I think what I'm after here is a group_concat on the column, not the rows. Just to clarify. I actually saw this after I posted for help.

Comment: The view makes the data materialize the tags to become multiple tags treated as a single value. So, GROUP_CONCAT will not be of help to you for the view.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm seeing. Thanks for clarifying that. What about a `group by` statement? I'm trying that now and it will not allow me to group by the alias. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like I'm going to have the same exact issue with the `group by` clause, because the tag values that the view is spitting out are, as you say, a single value. So, the bottom line Rolando is that I won't be able to use the view, am I right?

Comment: I added a convoluted query solution to turn the group_concat output into a temp table of fruits. I then applied group_concat again.

Comment: Uhhhhh... Thanks, Rolando. I don't think I've even seen half the functions you're using in that solution. :)  Yes, it is certainly convoluted, you're right about that. I don't think this would work though because you are referencing figs, apples and oranges. These are actually dynamic values and additional values can be added at any time, which it looks like I would need to manually add to the code. Unless, of course, I'm not seeing something.

Comment: To bring closure to this, just don't use the view

Comment: My solution dynamically unites all the fruits into a single SQL statement. Nothing is hardcoded. This weird solution would works no matter how many fruits each tag has (the exception would be a blank tag).

Comment: Thanks, Rolando! I truly appreciate all the help. I actually learned something here today! It's always a good day when that happens. :)